# EXCEL: check if {list of items} appear in another {list of items}

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list1 and want to check if its listed in List2. This will be used in filter formula in excel as criteria e.g. FILTER($A$1:$E$100,list1=list2).

I have tried many other approaches (Vlookup, Countifs etc) but it only lookup one value at a time. In MS Access SQL, this can be achieved using In(list2 items)

Any ideas?

| List1 | List2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| C | C |
| D |  |
| E |  |

Comment: Instead of `List1=List2` you should be using `ISNUMBER(MATCH(List1,List2,0))`.

Comment: this further simplified the formula. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can try the following formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$1:$A$5, MATCH($B$1:$B3, $A$1:$A$5, 0)),"")
```

Adapt the ranges to suit yours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in right direction - reverse of your formula works for me. I fix it for my use.